# Viewing and Modifying all TextViews across the device?

Tags: android, textview

Sorry for the poorly worded title, allow me to explain.

I have an idea for a translator app that will translate any text across all apps. Is it possible to create a listener that can watch all apps, and whenever a TextView is created, modify the content if the content contains a certain keyword?

Thanks!

Comment: @tinysunlight Maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible through the [`Accessibility API`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html), by implementing an `AccessibilityService`. I've never used it myself, so I'm not sure, though.

But [`AccessibilityNodeInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html) sounds promising:

> This class represents a node of the window content as well as actions that can be requested from its source.